# How to pass a password to scp with Turtle?

Tags: bash, haskell-turtle

This is what I got:

```
shell
    "scp -r /path_to_some_dir some_user@some_ip:destination_path"
    empty
```

and, naturally, I get prompted for the password.

Can the inputting of the password be automated with Turtle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you must use a password, you could use `sshpass`:

```
shell
    "sshpass -p \"password\" scp -r /path_to_some_dir some_user@some_ip:destination_path"
    empty
```

You could also use the argument `-f` and supply it with a text file containing the password instead, e.g. if you don't want the password to be hard-coded into your script, or displayed in the bash history.

Otherwise you could consider using SSH keys instead.

Comment: Good enough for getting me out of the hurry, but I hope that Turtle has another way of doing it.